# Powershell - VirtualBox Cloning Script Error

Tags: powershell, virtualbox

Code:

```
[string]$vmPath = "C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox VMs\"
[string]$vmName="Xubuntu_Version_"
[string]$vBoxManage = "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"
[string]$vBoxClonevdi = "clonevdi"
[string]$vBoxVMName = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox VMs\log.txt"
[string]$invokeCommand 
[string]$filetype=".vdi"
[string]$writeVersiontoText
[string]$vBoxManagewithQuotes= ([char]34 +$vBoxManage + [char]34 + " " +$vBoxClonevdi)

if(Test-Path ("C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox VMs\log.txt")){

    [int]$ConvertNum = -1
    [int]::TryParse($vBoxVMName.Substring(16), [ref]$ConvertNum)

    Write-Output ("Version Number: " + $ConvertNum)
    $ConvertAfter = $ConvertNum + 1
    Write-Output ("New Version: " + $ConvertAfter)

    $writeVersiontoText = $vmPath+$vmName+$ConvertAfter+$filetype
    $write= ($vmName + $ConvertAfter) 

    $invokeCommand = ($vBoxManagewithQuotes + " " + [char]34+$vmPath+$vmName+$ConvertNum + [char] 34  + " " + [char]34+$writeVersiontoText+ [char]34) 
    Write-Output $invokeCommand


    Invoke-Expression $invokeCommand

   if(Test-Path ($writeVersiontoText)){
            $write | Set-Content "C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox VMs\log.txt"
  }

 }
```

Problem:

I'm writing a script that uses the Virtual Box Manage utility (VBoxManage.exe) to clone a virtual machine. The issue I'm having is that it give me an error on the clonevdi part. What exactly is wrong and how do I fix it?

Error Report:

```
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:53
+ "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonevdi   "C:\Users\someuser\Virt ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'clonevdi' in expression or statement.
At line:27 char:9
+         Invoke-Expression $invokeCommand
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression],      ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

I think you just need to change this:

```
Invoke-Expression $invokeCommand
```

to this:

```
& $vBoxManage $vBoxClonevdi ([char]34+$vmPath+$vmName+$ConvertNum + [char] 34  + " " + [char]34+$writeVersiontoText+ [char]34)
```

Longer answer:

I would not use [char] 34 in code, I would escape double quotes with a backtick (`) and reconstruct your variables so they are simpler to read.

Then, using the call operator (&) will allow an executable to be invoked. Such executable needs to have its own variable, otherwise Powershell will look for an executabled named after the exec + the parameters provided. Additional parameters need to be added after the executable variable, hence the following construction:

```
& $vBoxManage $vBoxManage other params here
```

Comment: Is it possible to get it working with Invoke Command? No particular reason just wondering.

Comment: Yes, but it would look similar: `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { & $vBoxManage  params here }`